# Get the formula to calculate sales compounded growth per month based on Yearly expected income

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hi all and thanks for the help in advance.

I want to write a formula in excel. I tried to write it first in paper but I had some difficulties. Here the problem:

I need a formula to **monthly growth %** based on the *annual growth* and *total yearly sales*.

Total yearly sales is a known number. For example:
Sales in January 2024 (starting point) = 5€
Total sales 2024 = 100€
Total sales 2025 = 800€

The formula I look for would take the initial sales of 5 in January multiplied by (1+ growth rate) leading to february sales. After doing it for every month of the year I would get a summatory of 100€ in 2024.

Then, taking as starting point the sales of December 2024 of 13€ and the growth rate of 2025 I would get to a total of 800€ in 2025.

I include an screenshot to illustrate. The question would be, what would be the formula to get the growth rate in red:

[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5rgJ.png)

Comment: Assuming that the **unknown** growth rate factor is $~(1 + i) = x,~$ the January sales are $~J,~$ and the target annual sales is $~T,~$ notice that $$J \times \left(1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{11}\right) = J \times \frac{x^{12} - 1}{x-1} = T.$$  To the best of my knowledge, there is no analytical solution to (for example) $$Jx^{12} - J = Tx - T.$$  So, you have to resort to numerical approximation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The equation I was trying to write was something like this:
 J x (1+x) + J x (1+x)^2 + J x (1+x)^3 ... J x (1+x)^11 = T

Would this equation have the same result as the one you wrote above?

Comment: If you compare mine with yours, and change $~(1 + x)~$ to $~(1 + i) = x,~$ you find that yours is the same as mine, except that you omitted the January sales.